Как завернуть socks5 в тунель?
Имеется Raspberry pi и на нем клиент xray-core в режиме прокси который смотрит в щзаграничный интернет, надо завернуть этот прокси в тунель, что бы в последующем на роутере пробросить часть траффика через этот тунель. Как это можно реализовать? пробовал redsocks, tun2socks, но что то с ними не сраслось

Настрой любой VPN на узле с socks-proxy, подключайся к нему по vpn, вот тебе и туннель.
